# Anything wrong with "throw" inside a PTY.spawn?

Tags: ruby, process

This is a for a dev machine and testing purposes. I'm trying to start a script that starts a server, then ignores it once the output meets a condition. The process does not end, so I can't use backticks. I will be `-QUIT`ing the process independently (somewhere else in the script). So far this is the closest I've got:

```
require "pty"
catch :ready do
  begin
    PTY.spawn( "bin/start" ) do |stdin, stdout, pid|
      begin
        stdin.each { |line|
          throw(:ready) if line['worker ready']
        }
      rescue Errno::EIO
        puts "no more output"
      end
    end
  rescue PTY::ChildExited
    puts "child process exit"
  end
end # === end of catch block

# Continue with the rest of the script...
```

So far it works, but I am new to Ruby and processes. All the other solutions I've seen online require pipes, forks, and `Process.detach`.  Am I doing anything wrong by using `throw` while I am in a `PTY.spawn`?